# IdentityServer4 link directly to Facebook authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have an IdentityServer4 app which has Facebook integration, this is working fine.

I also have an Angular2 app that makes use of the IdentityServer. Currently if the user wants to log in via Facebook they have to click 'login' which takes them to the IdentityServer and then click on the Facebook button.

I want to have a 'Facebook' button on my Angular app which then automatically redirects them straight to Facebook, bypassing the main login screen.

I noticed the following line the the code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ...
    if (vm.IsExternalLoginOnly)
    {
        // only one option for logging in
        return ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First().AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl);
    }
    ...
}
```

Which is basically what I want, automatically redirect to Facebook. So I added the following method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> FacebookLogin(string returnUrl)
{
    var vm = await _account.BuildLoginViewModelAsync(returnUrl);

    // only one option for logging in
    return ExternalLogin(vm.ExternalProviders.First(x => x.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "FACEBOOK").AuthenticationScheme, returnUrl);
}
```

While this does redirect straight to Facebook and does authenticate, it doesn't redirect back to the calling app. I can see errors logged regarding invalid redirectUri, I assume this is because I'm not calling `connect/authorize`?

So is there a way to pass an additional parameter to `connect/authorize` to specify to use Facebook that I can then use in my controller, or call a different method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a provision to do this in the OIDC specification which is indeed supported by IdentityServer4.

Include the `acr_values` parameter in your Angular2 oidc-client configuration. A value like this should tell the Identity Server to forward your request onto the identity provider: "idp:oidc-facebook". Of course, that IdP will need to be registered with your IdentityServer instance.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping it was an easy implementation! Must have missed that in the docs. Just a note though, I had to set the value to 'idp:Facebook' for it to work, and it is case sensitive.